# In layman terms: Relation between Google Apps Script and Google Cloud Platform

Tags: google-app-engine, google-apps-script, google-cloud-platform

I am starting out with Google Apps Script, but as learning graph is growing exponentially few terms are getting hard to grasp.

Can anyone simply explain me about relationship between GAS and Googles Cloud Platform. How they are related? When there is a need of GCP when working with GAS? 
Whats difference between creating project on Developer Console and creating on Cloud console?

Please add comment if need any rectification in question, i'll be happy to do that.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Google Apps Script](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/) is part of the [G-Suite products](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/), generally not related to the [Google Cloud Platform products](https://cloud.google.com/products/) in ways other than being both Google products.

From the developer/customer prospectve occasionally there may be some marginal interactions between the products, but in a very limited manner - special situations. There *might* be more interactions on Google's infra side, but they're transparent for developers/customers.

So normally there is no **need** for GCP when working with GAS (or viceversa) unless it's for one of those very particular interaction situations, **specifically documented**.

For example

- the [Cloud Resource Manager](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/) is aware of and can deal differently with G-Suite customers. From [Acquiring an Organization resource](https://cloud.google.com/resource-manager/docs/creating-managing-organization#acquiring):

> - **G Suite:**
>
>   - The first time a user in your domain creates a project, the    Organization resource is automatically created and linked to your
>       company’s G Suite account. The current project and all future
>       projects will automatically belong to the organization.

- a while ago mapping a Google App Engine application to a custom domain was only possible through G-Suite (known as Google Apps at the time).

It's not uncommon for various documentation/guides, including those G-Suite related (either Google's or from third parties) to reference GCP products, but usually that's because of the convenience of using them, not because they are actually needed.

So you really need to be aware of which family the product/documentation you're using is part of. The GCP products and documentation are a lot better of consistently identifying themselves a being part of GCP.

Finally the Developer Console is just the older, but still widely used name of the Cloud Console, they're the same thing - used for GCP. Unless you're referring to [the Admin Console](https://admin.google.com) which is used for G-Suite.

Comment: So, when we write script whose method is to be get called uisng Execution API, why we have to associate the calling as well as target project's script to the GCP project ?

Comment: Because the Execution API allows external apps (i.e. not from `script.google.com`) access Apps Script capabilities, using OAuth. The OAuth implementation itself is probably the GCP one. See https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/rest/api#requirements. If you only execute your script via `script.google.com` you don't need GCP.

Comment: Each time a GAS project is created in script.google.com, a project is also created in console.cloud.google.com <YOUR ORG> > system-gsuite > apps-script.  So the relation is certainly there.